# Why I receive no WT_PACKETEXT window messages after initializing Wintab extensions?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm currently trying to process the absolute value of a drawing tablet's touch ring, through the Wintab API.  However, despite following instructions as they are described in the documentation, it seems like the WTOpen call doesn't set any extension settings.  Using the touch ring after initializing Wintab still triggers the default events, while the default events for pen inputs are suppressed and all pen inputs related to my application instead.

Here are the relevant segments of code:

```
...

#include "wintab.h"
#define PACKETDATA (PK_X | PK_Y | PK_Z | PK_NORMAL_PRESSURE | PK_ORIENTATION | PK_TIME | PK_BUTTONS)
#define PACKETMODE 0
#define PACKETTOUCHSTRIP PKEXT_ABSOLUTE
#define PACKETTOUCHRING PKEXT_ABSOLUTE
#include "pktdef.h"

...

internal b32
InitWinTab(HWND Window, window_mapping *Map)
{
    if(!LoadWintabFunctions())
        return false;

    LOGCONTEXT Tablet;
    AXIS TabletX, TabletY, TabletZ, Pressure;

    if(!gpWTInfoA(WTI_DEFCONTEXT, 0, &Tablet))
        return false;
    gpWTInfoA(WTI_DEVICES, DVC_X, &TabletX);
    gpWTInfoA(WTI_DEVICES, DVC_Y, &TabletY);
    gpWTInfoA(WTI_DEVICES, DVC_Z, &TabletZ);
    gpWTInfoA(WTI_DEVICES, DVC_NPRESSURE, &Pressure);

    UINT TouchStripOffset = 0xFFFF;
    UINT TouchRingOffset = 0xFFFF;
    for(UINT i = 0, ScanTag = 0; gpWTInfoA(WTI_EXTENSIONS + i, EXT_TAG, &ScanTag); i++)
    {
        if (ScanTag == WTX_TOUCHSTRIP)
            TouchStripOffset = i;
        if (ScanTag == WTX_TOUCHRING)
            TouchRingOffset = i;
    }

    Tablet.lcOptions |= CXO_MESSAGES;
    Tablet.lcPktData = PACKETDATA;
    Tablet.lcPktMode = PACKETMODE;
    Tablet.lcMoveMask = PACKETDATA;
    Tablet.lcBtnUpMask = Tablet.lcBtnDnMask;
    Tablet.lcInOrgX = 0;
    Tablet.lcInOrgY = 0;
    Tablet.lcInExtX = TabletX.axMax;
    Tablet.lcInExtY = TabletY.axMax;

    if(TouchStripOffset != 0xFFFF)
    {
        WTPKT DataMask;
        gpWTInfoA(WTI_EXTENSIONS + TouchStripOffset, EXT_MASK, &DataMask);
        Tablet.lcPktData |= DataMask;
    }
    if(TouchRingOffset != 0xFFFF)
    {
        WTPKT DataMask;
        gpWTInfoA(WTI_EXTENSIONS + TouchRingOffset, EXT_MASK, &DataMask);
        Tablet.lcPktData |= DataMask;
    }

    Map->AxisMax.x = (r32)TabletX.axMax;
    Map->AxisMax.y = (r32)TabletY.axMax;
    Map->AxisMax.z = (r32)TabletZ.axMax;
    Map->PressureMax = (r32)Pressure.axMax;

    if(!gpWTOpenA(Window, &Tablet, TRUE))
        return false;

    return(TabletX.axMax && TabletY.axMax && TabletZ.axMax && Pressure.axMax);
}

...

        case WT_PACKET:
        {
            PACKET Packet;
            if(gpWTPacket((HCTX)LParam, (UINT)WParam, &Packet)) 
            {
                ...
            }
        } break;

        case WT_PACKETEXT:
        {
            PACKETEXT Packet;
            if(gpWTPacket((HCTX)LParam, (UINT)WParam, &Packet)) 
            {
                ...
            }
        } break;

...
```

The bitmask for the packet data in the initialization have sensible bits set for both extensions and don't overlap with the existing bitmask.  No stage of the initialization fails.  WT_PACKET gets called only with valid packet data while WT_PACKETEXT never gets called.  Furthermore, calling WTPacketsGet with a PACKETEXT pointer on the HCTX returned by WTOpen fills the packet with garbage from the regular packet queue.  This leaves me with the conclusion that somehow WTOpen didn't receive notification that the extensions should be loaded and I'm unable to find what else I should define in the LOGCONTEXT data structure to change that.

Is there a mistake in my initialization?  Or is there a way to get a better readout to why the extensions didn't load?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that a driver setting prevented the extension packets from being sent, in favor of using the touch ring for different function.  Changing this setting resolved the issue.  The code didn't contain any errors itself.